# Icinga displays binary output to browser

Tags: nginx, icinga

Can't tell if this is Icinga or nginx, but when I pull up Icinga classic web I get the binary cgi displayed on the screen.

Here's a screenshot: [image: http://i.imgur.com/ZHFYB4k.png]

It seems to be the binary data from "tag.cgi".

Here's my nginx config:

```
     # Icinga ---------------------------------------------------------
     location /icinga/ {
               alias                   /usr/share/webapps/icinga/;
               auth_basic              "Icinga Access";
               auth_basic_user_file    /etc/icinga/htpasswd.users;
     }

     location ~ ^/icinga/(.*)\.cgi$ {
              root           /usr/share/webapps/;
              fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
              include        fastcgi.conf;
              fastcgi_param  AUTH_USER          $remote_user;
              fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
              # rewrite        ^/icinga/cgi-bin/(.*)\.cgi /$1.cgi break;
              include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
              fastcgi_index  index.php;
              fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
              auth_basic     "Icinga Access";
              auth_basic_user_file    /etc/icinga/htpasswd.users;
              }
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Icinga main page consist of three frame

1. The left panel which consists of **pure HTML** *menu.html*
2. The top panel which consists of **CGI output** *cgi-bin/tac.cgi?tac_header*
3. The main window which consists of **CGI output** too *cgi-bin/tac.cgi?tac_header*

The reason your `nginx` spitting the binary instead CGI-generated page is, you pass the request to **PHP-FPM** socket. PHP FPM process only understands PHP language, but the Icinga itself [written mainly in C/C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icinga#Architecture).

By default Nginx can't handle CGI, so you must add another CGI wrapper in your server, for example [fcgiwrap](http://wiki.nginx.org/Fcgiwrap). Icinga official wiki has example of nginx configuration in [this page](https://wiki.icinga.org/display/howtos/Setting+up+Icinga+with+Nginx)